# node server not running : exiting without any output

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been messing around with codesphere lately and have a weird issue, at least to me:
my server.js:

```
const express =require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8000;

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  res.send('Hi there')
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Running")
});
```

Upon npm start :

```
user@codesphere:app [master] $ npm start

personal_website@1.0.0 start /home/user/app
node server.js
```

then the output exits the server and returns to CLI

Output for running node server.js:
[image]

Another edit:
upper part, my package.json in their ide, lower part: package.json open in terminal (nano)
Now I actually think, it is save to assume they have trouble!
[image]

Comment: Instead of `npm start`, you can directly use `node server.js`. That should work. If you want to run using `npm start`, your `package.json` should be configured accordingly.

Comment: node server.js directly closes the server again, I'll edit my package.json above! Rather: If codesphere allows me to open files again ... it seems oddly buggy today! I'll keep u posted if anything changes. 
thanks so far

Comment: Using `node server.js` and above mentioned code, its working fine in my system and the root endpoint is also working. Can you share the output on running `node server.js`.

Comment: there is absolutely no output. I'll attach a screenshot. see above! 
maybe it's their fault :-/

Comment: Type `node --help`. Make sure it is Node.js and not [some other node](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/node).

Comment: It is node.Js . Rather unfortunate. I fear the worst!